# Reshape data for facetgrid plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have data given below. I am trying to create facetgrid plot.  How can I reshape my data similar to the time column present  in the tips dataset? This will help in creating the facetgrid plot as shown below.

```
data = {'type':['nlp', 'computer vision', 'reinforcement learning', 'nlp', 'nlp'], 
        'keyword':[['skip grams', 'negative sampling'], ['semantic segmentation', 'sift', 'hog', 'object recognition'], ['monte carlo methods','direct policy search'], ['bert', 'masked language model', 'attention'],['word embedding', 'tf idf']]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

dataframe

```
type    keyword
0   nlp [skip grams, negative sampling]
1   computer vision [semantic segmentation, sift, hog, object reco...
2   reinforcement learning  [monte carlo methods, direct policy search]
3   nlp [bert, masked language model, attention]
4   nlp [word embedding, tf idf]
```

seaborn tips dataset

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips.head()
```

tips dataframe

```
total_bill  tip     sex  smoker day time    size
0   16.99   1.01    Female  No  Sun Dinner  2
1   10.34   1.66    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
2   21.01   3.50    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
3   23.68   3.31    Male    No  Sun Dinner  2
4   24.59   3.61    Female  No  Sun Dinner  4
```

creating facetgrid

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time")
g.map(sns.histplot, "tip")
```

Plot

[image]

Comment: what is your required reshape?

Comment: @SandrinJoy I want to format the keyword column so I can use FacetGrid plot on it. In the tips dataset, please check the time column here.

Comment: The "tip" column is numeric. How do wanna plot a histogram from categories? What's the expected output? Either you transform your data to numerical or choose a different plot. Take a look [at this tutorial from seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html).